# How to add to URL?

Tags: javascript, url

I am creating a filtering functionality and I would like to add the selected filters to the url for navigation purposes. Here is an array of objects:

```
let arr = [
{available:true},
{variantOption:{name:"size",value:"2XL"}},
{productType:"Apparel"}
]
```

I need it in the following format which I think are according to the W3c guidelines:

[www.whatever.com/collection?available=true&productType=apparel&somethingElse=something](http://www.whatever.com/collection?available=true&productType=apparel&somethingElse=something) etc

I am not able to figure out how to add something like variantOption key and values to the url in format like so. So that when I retrieve the values from the URL, they end up in the same format like the original array of objects was, which I want to use for the api call.

I would be using window.history.pushState for this use case here.

Comment: it seems your url is cut off

Comment: I added an answer. please check it out. and if it gave you the solution you needed, please mark it as the right answer. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the array.

`for (let item of arr) {`

then you will need to get each key of the object (item).

`for (let key in item)`

because one of them is another object you will need to check if the value is object

`if (typeof item[key] === "object")`

if true,

you need to loop one more time to get the extra key value pairs and pass them to the url as params..

`for (let innerKey in item[key]) {`

`newLink.searchParams.set(innerKey, item[key][innerKey]);`

else,

just take the key and value  and pass them to the url as params.

`newLink.searchParams.set(key, item[key]);`

---

the loop at the end should look like this:

```
const newLink = new URL(window.location.href); // here you  can put any base url
for (let item of arr) {
  for (let key in item) {
    if (typeof item[key] === "object") {
      for (let innerKey in item[key]) {
        newLink.searchParams.set(innerKey, item[key][innerKey]);
      }
    } else {
      newLink.searchParams.set(key, item[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

and then to use the `newLink.href` as the url. you mentioned that you want to use window.history.pushState . so you can call the function and pass the url as argument.

example here: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-mclaren-zwe598?file=/src/index.js)